# PulseAudio: Get current volume of source (microphone)

Tags: linux, bash, volume, microphone, pulseaudio

I need a way to get the current "loudness" of a microphone via PulseAudio (via bash). And I mean the volume of the sound that is picked up by the mircophone.

I want to replicate a volume meter, like you see it in pavucontrol.

Answer (score 1):

search on github for the [raspberry-vu project](https://github.com/rm-hull/raspberry-vu/) as it can help you with this. i changed `src/impulse.c` to use the device `alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo`, you may need to change this for your setup.

i then linked the GNU GSL lib to analyze the FFT array returned by `im_getSnapshot()` using `gsl_stats_sd()` and `gsl_stats_mean()` both of which return a `double`. you can then react to the value returned.